# Performing anomalie detection on a battery volatge using LSTM-RNN

Tags: time-series, regression, lstm, anomaly-detection

I am trying to detect anomalies in a battery output voltage for one month.

I have the next data frame, as it is shown the data is collected each minute for each day so I have almost 1420 sample per day.

[image]

Should I use the 'time' or the 'date' column in my time series analysis?
I could not find an example like my situation all dataframes I found looks like the next :

[image]

It is all about a unique value for each day. Please any help is appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the "date" and "time" columns to pre-process your data and to construct your neural net input.

RNN does not work well for very long-term dependancies... so, for example, creating a time series with all minutes in a month, won't probably work.

You must select:

- How many samples your input data will have
- What is your sampling period (minute, hour, day, week...)
- What do you want to detect: If the input data contains an anomally or you might want to predict  if an anomally will occur in the future...

When you have all of this, and perhaps something else, defined you will have to use your "date" and "time" columns to create the dataset (the time-series)

Furthermore, I don't know if all batteries are checked under the same circunstances, for instance, are all of them new stock ones? If not, you can also use those columns to compute battery age or "working time" as an extra feature.

Comment: Normally I need to detect anomally means when the voltage goes behind a threshold. My row data contains a sampling rate that corresponds to 1 min, should I reduce it ? how to choose the sampling period?. For batteries, I splitted the dataset it corresponds to a unique one

Comment: In LSTM is it possible to give as input more than one column?

Comment: The sampling period is something you have to come up with... there is no a recipe, every problem is different, You might do some research in the literature. The LSTM can accept an input with the following shape: (batch_size, num_samples, features)

Comment: you means I need to perform some plots before choosing my sampling rate?

Comment: For sure, always after digging into the Deep Learning, you must perform as much as Exploratory Data Analysis as you can. You need to know very well how your data look like because, perhaps, you won't need a neurla network to solve your problem. For time-series you have ARIMA, even Bayesian Filters and other well-knonw techniques. Other considerations, is your data labeled, I mean, do you know the threshold?

Comment: Actually I have no idea about the threshold. However I know the output should be between 24-29V so each output under or above is not acceptable